# "Diff, save or kill" when killing buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs

When trying to kill a buffer that contains changes in Emacs, the message:
" Buffer [buffer] modified; kill anyway? (yes or no)" is displayed.

Instead of this I'd like to have Emacs ask me if I want to:
 1. View a diff of what changed, 
 2. Save the buffer, 
 3. Kill the buffer.

How?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626492/emacs-highlight-buffer-modifications

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer lies in using [advice](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_212.html), because the hooks normally run when killing buffers run **after** the "buffer modified" prompt you want to change.

The following advice does what you want (I think).  A couple of notes:

1. When running the diff, the original buffer is marked as not modified - but you'll really need to save it.
2. The other buffer in the diff doesn't get deleted

`(defadvice kill-buffer (around my-kill-buffer-check activate)
  "Prompt when a buffer is about to be killed."
  (let* ((buffer-file-name (buffer-file-name))
         backup-file)
    ;; see 'backup-buffer
    (if (and (buffer-modified-p)
             buffer-file-name
             (file-exists-p buffer-file-name)
             (setq backup-file (car (find-backup-file-name buffer-file-name))))
        (let ((answer (completing-read (format "Buffer modified %s, (d)iff, (s)ave, (k)ill? " (buffer-name))
                                       '("d" "s" "k") nil t)))
          (cond ((equal answer "d")
                 (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
                 (let ((orig-buffer (current-buffer))
                       (file-to-diff (if (file-newer-than-file-p buffer-file-name backup-file)
                                         buffer-file-name
                                       backup-file)))
                   (set-buffer (get-buffer-create (format "%s last-revision" (file-name-nondirectory file-to-diff))))
                   (buffer-disable-undo)
                   (insert-file-contents file-to-diff nil nil nil t)
                   (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
                   (setq buffer-read-only t)
                   (ediff-buffers (current-buffer) orig-buffer)))
                ((equal answer "k")
                 (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
                 ad-do-it)
                (t
                 (save-buffer)
                 ad-do-it)))
      ad-do-it)))`

Comment: I put this in my init file. Now when I do M-x package-list-packages, Emacs keeps giving me the message "Buffer modified `*http elpa.gnu.org:80`*, diff, save, kill?". I suppose there's a way of modifying the code to avoid this, but I'm new to elisp.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to write some code to put in the [kill-buffer-hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Kill-Buffer.html) and  [write-file-functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Saving-Buffers.html) lists.  Conceptually, what you want to do is

1. test if the buffer has been modified
2. display your message and get a
   response, and do what's requested
3. then clear the modified flag so the
   normal kill-buffer doesn't come back
   and ask again.

Comment: The kill-buffer-hooks is run after the prompt the user is trying to change/avoid.