# Highlight buffer modifications

Tags: emacs

It often occurs that a file buffer is modified (duh!). Before exiting, emacs asks whether to save the changes. Now it would be interesting to know what actually changed. Is there a way to find out?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331569/diff-save-or-kill-when-killing-buffers-in-emacs

Answer (score 30):

As of Emacs 22.1 (at least), `'save-buffers-kill-emacs` (the default binding for <kbd>C-x C-c</kbd>) prompts you for each unsaved buffer that has a file.  Type a <kbd>d</kbd> when prompted to save and see the diff.

From the help documentation:

```
Save some modified file-visiting buffers.  Asks user about each one.
You can answer `y' to save, `n' not to save, `C-r' to look at the
buffer in question with `view-buffer' before deciding or `d' to
view the differences using `diff-buffer-with-file'.
```

If you look at the prompt, it should say something like:

```
Save file /path/to/file.txt? (y, n, !, ., q, C-r, d, or C-h)
```

Typing <kbd>C-h</kbd> gives you a little more verbose description (but <kbd>d</kbd> is what you are asking for):

```
Type SPC or `y' to save the current buffer;
DEL or `n' to skip the current buffer;
RET or `q' to give up on the save (skip all remaining buffers);
C-g to quit (cancel the whole command);
! to save all remaining buffers;
C-r to view this buffer;
d to view changes in this buffer;
or . (period) to save the current buffer and exit.
```

Answer (score 17):

I use diff-buffer-with-file, and select the file that the buffer came from (which is the default anyway for the command... just hit enter).

You can also use highlight-changes-mode, though this won't track changes until you turn it on, so not so useful if you want to see what changed when you're closing a file that has not been in this mode :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can have `highlight-changes-mode` enabled. It will display all changes in red. However it won't show you whitespace changes and will mark removals only with an red `_`. See also http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrackChanges.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21084181/1528712 this will make change mark show on the left fringe.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [post about tracking changes](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/05/tracking-changes.html) by djcb most helpful regarding tracking changes in Emacs. The trick is to add the following to your .emacs:

```
;; higlight changes in documents
(global-highlight-changes-mode t)
(setq highlight-changes-visibility-initial-state nil); initially hide
```

and then toggle highlight-changes-visible-mode when you want to see what has changed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I type undo to see the last change (usually some stray character which got typed in the wrong window, since I save early and often).

It would be nice if there were some other indication of the current changes, e.g. in the border like quick diff in Eclipse text editors.

Comment: And if the undo happens to undo an important change, you can just enter some character and run undo twice - thanks to Emacs's undo facility, which is more powerful than that in most editors.

Answer (score 0):

I use [goto-chg](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/goto-chg.el) for things like that.  It's not perfect, but it always is enough to jog my memory about what change I made and promptly forgot about.