# How can I display changed line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, line, highlight

Some text editors can display changed line by default. But in Emacs, how?

Answer (score 11):

The minor mode `highlight-changes-mode` displays text changes.

ADDITION:
I wrote some code of fringe support for `highlight-changes-mode`.

```
(eval-after-load "hilit-chg"
  '(progn
     (defvar highlight-fringe-mark 'filled-square
       "The fringe bitmap name marked at changed line.
Should be selected from `fringe-bitmaps'.")

     (defadvice hilit-chg-make-ov (after hilit-chg-add-fringe activate)
       (mapc (lambda (ov)
           (if (overlay-get ov 'hilit-chg)
           (let ((fringe-anchor (make-string 1 ?x)))
             (put-text-property 0 1 'display
                    (list 'left-fringe highlight-fringe-mark)
                    fringe-anchor)
             (overlay-put ov 'before-string fringe-anchor))
         ))
         (overlays-at (ad-get-arg 1))))))
```

[image: fringed]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/997008bd7f400c4c01f12288ad991b24.png))</sub>

ADDITION:
To remove highlights on save time, try it:

```
(add-hook 'after-save-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when highlight-changes-mode
              (save-restriction
                (widen)
                (highlight-changes-remove-highlight (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

Comment: I tried it. It's bit different from what I expected. It would be better that change mark show on the left fringe. But it's still useful. Thanks.

Comment: The fringe support code was added in my post. Please try it if you want.

Comment: That's a great piece of code. How is that not standard?  Not understandable... Though, how could it be adapted so that the marks in the fringe get removed every time we save?

Comment: This works perfectly, but there is one issue: the color of the changed text does not respect the syntax-highlighting. So I came up with a solution to add this this: https://pastebin.com/t5A5RQYQ

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're interested in changes between the buffer and the saved file.  I usually use `diff-buffer-with-file` for that, because I don't need it too often.

---

I also use `diff-hl` mode, which shows changed lines of the saved file vs. the last commit in a version control system.  It's available in Melpa.

Here's my config, which changes the indicators to '+', '-', and '!':

```
(setq diff-hl-fringe-bmp-function 'diff-hl-fringe-bmp-from-type)
(global-diff-hl-mode 1)
```

---

Though you didn't ask about it, I'll also mention that `vc` can easily diff files that are under version control with `C-x v =` (current file) or `C-x v D` (entire project).

Comment: Starting with version 1.5.0, you can `(setq diff-hl-fringe-bmp-function 'diff-hl-fringe-bmp-from-type)` to use this kind of bitmaps, or use a custom function, if you'd like to use some other bitmaps, or somehow different choosing logic.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks, that is much simpler.